# Is it true that two real matrices with the same characteristic polynomial have the same rank?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wandering if there is a chance that two real matrices with the same characteristic polynomial have a different rank?
I tried to prove it, but i failed.
any suggestions?

Comment: Take the zero two by two matrix and a nonzero zero two by two nilpotent matrix.

Comment: Here's a related question: Can two real matrices with the same *minimal* polynomial have different rank?

Answer (score 8):

$\pmatrix{0 & 1\\ 0&0}$ and $\pmatrix{0&0\\0&0}$ both have characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2$.